# Use image from different resource group in vmss created with arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

What specific syntax must be changed in the below example in order for an Azure Linux virtual machine scale set created in one resource group use an image that was created in a different, pre-existing resource group?

The images must remain in a separate resource group for many reasons, one of which is that the images and the scale sets have different life cycles.

[The Azure Quick Start guide at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-template-linux) gives an example arm template that includes a virtual machine scale set which specifies an image to use when the VMSS instantiates each VM.

The relevant parts of the Quickstart template in the link include:

The variables section summarized as:

```
"variables": {
   ...other variables
   "osType": {
      "publisher": "Canonical",
      "offer": "UbuntuServer",
      "sku": "16.04-LTS",
      "version": "latest"
    },
    "imageReference": "[variables('osType')]",
    ...other variables
  },
```

And the VirtualMachineProfile section of the VirtualMachinesScaleSets block as follows:

```
"virtualMachineProfile": {
    "storageProfile": {
      "osDisk": {
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite"
      },
      "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerNamePrefix": "[parameters('vmssName')]",
      "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
      "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPasswordOrKey')]",
      "linuxConfiguration": "[if(equals(parameters('authenticationType'), 'password'), json('null'), variables('linuxConfiguration'))]"
    },
    ...other config
}
```

It seems that the `publisher`, `author`, `sku`, and `version` fields within the `ostype` variable defined above need to be changed to refer to an instance of `Microsoft.Compute/images` which was created in a separate resource group.

We can get the fully qualified id of the images in the other resource group, and we can get any variables required to query.

But what specific syntax must we change in the ARM template given in the link and excerpts above?

Comment: Not an expert of these arm templates, but from [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2021-11-01/virtualmachinescalesets?tabs=json) here, I see you can define `id` inside `imageReference` block to point to the image resource id in the other resource group. 
May be you can put the `id` in the `osType` var but not set `offer`, `publisher` etc., of marketplace images.. 

This is bit vague as `osType` parameter is of `linux` or `windows` on schema but here in template it contains image parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what you're after (it shows image in the same RG):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vmss-windows-customimage/azuredeploy.json#L250

For a different RG you will have:

```json
"virtualMachineProfile": {
  "storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": {
      "id": "[resourceId(parameters('imageResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Compute/images', parameters('imageName'))]"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

If the image is in a different subscription you would add the subscriptionId:

```json
"id": "[resourceId(parameters('imageSubId'), parameters('imageResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Compute/images', parameters('imageName'))]"
```

That help?